# Excel display nth day of current month

Tags: excel, date, formula

I have a list of recurring bills. Some are on the 1st of every month, and some are on the 15th or 16th etc. What I want to be able to do is display this day within the current month. So if it is February, and the bill recurs on the 9th every month, my cell will show 02/09/12, and if it was march, it would show 03/09/12. Is there a formula or macro to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it to be: =DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),18)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the number 9 in A1 this formula will show the 9th of the current month (whether that be in the future or the past)

`=TODAY()-DAY(TODAY())+A1`

Answer (score -1):

edate(start-date),1)

ie  edate(B3,1)

b3= 1/5/13

Result = 5th of 1 month later - 2/5/13

3 for quarterly, 12 for annual

Comment: Could you please edit your answer and write in some sentence to your answer?